# For Flink v 1.10.1 or later how can you programmatically edit the container absolute path in a savepoint metadate file?

Tags: apache-flink

I am exploring how to change the absolute path contained in a Flink savepoint's metadata file.

We are looking to migrate a flink stream across AWS regions; however expect to run into problems because of this absolute path. Flink documentation alludes to this problem and suggests using the SavepointV2Serializer to edit the path:

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/savepoints.html#can-i-move-the-savepoint-files-on-stable-storage

Can anyone help me identify an example that illustrates how to do this? I have not been able to find a reference online.

Also, although looking in the _metadata file, I see an absolute path, I have not found any reference to it in the resulting deserialized objects, nor is it saved to a serialized file.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Here's the main file I wrote:

```
object Main extends App {
  val meta = "src" / "main" / "resources" / "_metadata"
  println( s"meta: ${meta.path}: ${meta.exists}" )
  val contents = meta.contentAsString
  println( contents )
//  val serde1 = SavepointV1Serializer.INSTANCE
  val serde2 = SavepointV2Serializer.INSTANCE

  import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

  val data = meta.inputStream() { in =>
    val dis = new java.io.DataInputStream( in )
    serde2.deserialize( dis, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader )
  }

  println( s"META: ${data}" )
  println( s"METADATA.version: ${data.getVersion}" )
  println( s"METADATA.checkpointId: ${data.getCheckpointId}" )
  println( s"METADATA.masterStates: ${Option( data.getMasterStates ).map( _.asScala.mkString( "[", ", ", "]" ) )}" )
  println(
    s"METADATA.operatorStates: ${Option( data.getOperatorStates ).map( _.asScala.mkString( "[", ", ", "]" ) )}"
  )
  println( s"METADATA.taskStates: ${Option( data.getTaskStates ).map( _.asScala.mkString( "[", ", ", "]" ) )}" )

  val newMeta = "src" / "main" / "resources" / "_NEW_metedata"

  val newData = new SavepointV2(
    data.getCheckpointId,
    Seq.empty[OperatorState].asJava,
    data.getMasterStates
  )
  println( s"NEW_DATA:OpStates: ${newData.getOperatorStates}" )

  newMeta.outputStream() { out =>
    serde2.serialize( newData, new java.io.DataOutputStream( out ) )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue was actually fixed in Flink 1.11 -- see [FLINK-5763](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5763) -- savepoints are now relocatable, and no longer contain absolute paths. The only exception seems to be if you use the `GenericWriteAheadLog` sink.

The documentation needs to be updated, see [FLINK-19381](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19381).

So if you can upgrade to 1.11.x first, then you should be able to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the news about the fix in 1.11. However, we need to support customers who are running 1.10 for at least six months. The documentation referenced suggests a preferred approach but neglects to further elaborate. Any project,article, etc that demonstrates how to edits the savepoint path would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of anything helpful. I suggest asking on the flink-user mailing list.